# c# identity get logged in user in api controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to get the logged in user in the web api controller. When I do this

```
User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

It returns null.

But my user is logged in. Anyone knows what is the issue?

These are what I am using in the API class

```
using AltuaWebsite.Core.Models;
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
```

This is how the users are logging in the system

```
public ActionResult Login(String email, String password)
{
    ApplicationUser user = UserManager.FindByName(email);

    if (user != null && checkRole("admin,user", user.Id) && UserManager.CheckPassword(user, password))
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, email)
                },
                DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);

        foreach (var role in user.Roles)
        {
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.Name));
        }

        Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            IsPersistent = true,
            ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24)
        }, identity);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Site");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add using System.Web.Http;

Comment: How did they login? a log in form in your app? NT authentication, basic authentication?

Comment: Please read [ask] and show what you have tried. Start by explaining what authentication you're using.

Comment: Where are you getting null for User.Identity.GetUserId();

Comment: In an another api controller.

Comment: How are you hosting the API? If it is self or owin hosted, your HttpContext will be null.

Comment: Yes it is Owin hosted.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the following directly in your controller

```
var claimsPrincipal = (ClaimsPrincipal)ActionContext.RequestContext.Principal;
```